# Add my app to “Share” button in gallery

Tags: ios, gallery, share

The idea is to select the photo, press the share button and select my installed app, and open my app with the photo selected (as Facebook or Twitter do).

It is possible on iOS (Android does it)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can achieve this using Share extension iOS8

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html

http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2014/10/8/xcode-6-tutorial-ios-8-simple-share-extension-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

You need to build an extension. Extensions have been available since iOS 8.

https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

It solved my problem:
You have to go in new/target, enter a name, and add the code like in this ticket:
[Ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562841/ios-i-installed-the-share-extension-but-impossible-to-get-the-image-selected-f?noredirect=1#comment80084772_46562841)