# iOS: I installed the Share Extension, but impossible to get the image selected from the gallery in my App

Tags: ios, objective-c, sharing, ios-app-extension

I used that [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBC2m8BbcCE) but impossible to get the selected image in my App. I created with "New/File/Target", then I added a group in the "Capabilities". I can see the share icon when I go to the image gallery, but it does nothing when I click on the button.

Code Example:

```
- (BOOL)isContentValid {
    // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
    return YES;
}

- (void)didSelectPost {
    // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.

    // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
    [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
}

- (NSArray *)configurationItems {
    // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
    return @[];
}
```

What I would like is after selecting the image(s), I click on the share button, I choose my app in the list, and then it opens my app with the image(s) retrieved.

[image]

I check that two examples in the Apple doc, but nothing's work:
[Open With...](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html)
[Uti from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html)

Here is what I did, but this technique works only from the mail app:
[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: can you have 120x120 app icon in your app ?

Comment: might be help you this link.. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794

Comment: Thanks but I need the inverse, I mean the fact that when I am in the image gallery for example, I can choose my app in the menu downstairs. Today, I can see the icon, I can click on it, no problem on that part. The problem is that it does nothing when I click on it...